# Issues with foreign key relationship

Tags: python, django

I have defined a relationship between two models of different app using foreign key and data is inserted into Db accurately with foreign key instance, but I want to fetch that data using Django ORM but I didn't get it, I have googled this issue and also checked stack-overflow questions but still my issues are not solved.

```
#models.py

class teamInfo(models.Model):       
    ownerID = models.IntegerField()
    teamName = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __unicode__(self):
         return unicode(self.id)

class gameWorld(models.Model):
    team = models.ForeignKey(teamInfo)
    w = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    l = models.IntegerField(null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.id)
```

I have tried a few things in my views but nothing worked for me.  Here is the latest thing I have tried in my views:

```
def teamStandings(request,template=None,context=None):

    getAllTeamStat = gameWorld.objects.all()

    for i in getAllTeamStat.teaminfo_set.select_related() :
        raise Exception(i.teaminfo.teamName)
```

I simply want a Django ORM query which fetches data from both models so I can display the team name in templates

Answer (score 0):

See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview) and try that:

```
class TeamStandingsView(ListView):
    model = gameWorld
    template = # Some template path here!
    context_object_name = "games"
```

in template:

```
{% for game in games %}
    {{ game.team.teamName }} 
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score -3):

edit: this should work:

```
def teamStandings(request,template=None,context=None):
        getAllTeamStat=gameWorld.objects.all()
        for team in getAllTeamStat:
            for teaminfo in team.teaminfo_set.all():
                 print teaminfo.teamName
```

Comment: I am getting this error whatever I use 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'teaminfo_set'  Or 'teamInfo_set'

Comment: This won't work because `gameWorld.objects.all()` will return a QuerySet and throw an error when calling `teaminfo_set`.

Comment: There is no valid "reverse" relationship here. You can use reverse only if you start with teamInfo Model. Here you can just access team from your QuerySet

Comment: that's true. i forget a for.